# Using differential equation to estimate epistemological growth constant

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request

I found some tweets ([1](https://twitter.com/DangerKidChris/status/894744196212441088),[2](https://twitter.com/DangerKidChris/status/894744650438680578)) describing a philosophy paper as follows:

> I came across this paper from the academic journal of philosophy that
>   tries to solve a differential equation for an epistemological
>   constant; more specifically a growth constant that bridges the gap
>   between the essence of and the physical of said thing.

This person doesn't remember the original reference, and I've had no luck with search engines.

The closest I have found were some papers in scientometrics (e.g. Szydłowski & Krawiec, [2001](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1012751028630)), and in *The Journal of Philosophy* the closest match seems to be Grene & Ravetz ([1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2022829)) on Leibniz.

Does anyone know the reference for this specific paper?

Comment: TBH this sounds like bad science or a bad remembering. Even if there is a differential equation that's purported to measure the gap between the "essence" and the "physical", I can't imagine any convincing empirical evidence for its validity.

Comment: Well sure, it would be silly to interpret such results as ‘true’ in a scientific sense—it’s more that the idea is sufficiently whacked that I’d love to see how they go about it.